# Is there a Control or Panel in DevExpress XtraForm that I can design something like a collapsePanel?

Tags: c#, devexpress

I look out for something that looks like for example the searchoption in Visual Studio (with a little plus or minus in the upper corner, so that I can click on it and it shows or don't shows the options I have).

The "GroupBox" comes close to what I want to design, but I don't find an adjustment or a property which I can change, so that I can collapse the box.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the [Flyout Panel](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/114578/Controls-and-Libraries/Messages-Notifications-and-Dialogs/Flyout-Panel).

Comment: Thank you, but that's not exactly what I was looking for. But I found this https://documentation.devexpress.com/WPF/DevExpress.Xpf.LayoutControl.GroupBox.MinimizeElementVisibility.property (unfortunately its contained in v19.1 and I have v18.1)

Comment: Are you using WPF or WinForms? The LayoutControlGroup allows for collapsing in version 18.1

Comment: Oh sorry, I use WinForms (didn't know that there is a difference since now). However, I found what I need now: https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraLayout.LayoutGroup.ExpandButtonVisible.property   Thanks for your help :)